# IllegalStateException: meta-data tag in the AndroidManifest doesn't have a right value

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemaptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <permission
        android:name="ca.sfu.cmpt276.bfraser.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="ca.sfu.cmpt276.bfraser.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
         The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBR9iGtWO-bIbQ7-Fpxd8HFe9cZ53RX_Vo" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Trying to figure out how Google Maps integrate with Android and Eclipse, I followed the documentation and did what I was supposed to, but I keep getting the error mentioned in the title, saying that the value isn't right, it is expecting 5089000, but is getting 0, presumably from the line

> android:name="com.google.gms.version"
>               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Googling this error, I've found out that most people forgot this meta-data tag, but as you can see, I put it where it's supposed to be, and I've also imported the proper library and included it in the project, but I'm still getting the error.

Anything else that might be causing this?

I've got the proper API key generated, I've downloaded Google Play Services via SDK and I don't see that I've missed any steps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
```

not

```
android:name="com.google.gms.version"
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure where I got the line as it was, now I feel like an idiot, spending an hour trying to figure out what it was.

Comment: @VaporTrails happens :) It's always easier (for me) to spot mistakes in code that is not your own.